No value attribute in input element when renders from Svelte
Can someone explain to me why if I create input component in Svelte, using html input like, for example
<input type="text" id="testId" name="name" value="random text">

the value attribute doesn't render in DOM?
However the value property is in the element and its value can be picked up but for some reason I would like to know why there is no value attribute rendered.
It's the same for type="number" but for type="hidden" value attribute renders OK.

If you disable client-side JS in your web browser and try again, is the value attribute still not rendered? Because it is not a problem that it is not rendered with JS enabled? The reason for it I don't know, but it's an internal decision taken by the Svelte developers to make it work like this, and for us who use Svelte it shouldn't be a problem, and not something we should need to care about.

Disabling client-js didn't solve the problem. And, yes, that was my thought as well, that was done by Svelte developers for a reason. And agree that we shouldn't worry about it when working in Svelte. The issue I've got is on backend side which is PHP and HTML/JS in PHP project where I need to embed a Svelte input component. Finally I've manage to fix it and it was nothing to do with missing value attribute. I just wanted to know why, by the way.
Thanks for confirming my belie that it was up to Svelte people.

That the value attribute is not present in the HTML code when client-side JS is disabled sounds like a very big bug to me. I recommend you to reate a minimal reproducible example and post a bug issue to let the developers know about it.

They know about it and it's been fixed in upcoming version (5)

In the current codebase (for upcoming v5) there is a function called remove_input_attr_defaults with this documentation:

The value/checked attribute in the template actually corresponds to the defaultValue property, so we need
to remove it upon hydration to avoid a bug when someone resets the form value.

This reasoning is a bit odd, since this might be exactly what people expect: That it resets to the given value.
Related issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8220
As of now, it will set the attribute in v5 for fully static values (see this comment).
